# Shuffle Tracking in Blackjack

Tags: probability, probability-theory, card-games

I'm a professional card counter, i developed a software that let me count cards in Blackjack very easily, and now i'm trying to implement an algorithm that lets me see all the probabilities of one card to show up from the deck, let me be more clear, having a text file like this that contains all the cards that left the deck in succession:

```
244QJX966AK37A... and so on
```

i should be able to see all the odds of drawing a certain card.

The problem is that i don't know the mathematical approach to this problem. Thanks in advance to all those who want to contribute. I also posted a question on Stack Overflow where i will post the code after knowing all i need.

Comment: The question on Stack Overflow is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241392/shuffle-tracking-in-blackjack

Comment: The question asked in your post body is completely unrelated to shuffle tracking as I've seen blackjack players use the term. Maybe you should edit the post title to "Probability of a card being dealt in blackjack"?

Comment: As a professional card counter, do you actually remember the *order* in which cards have left the deck in succession, or do you use some *summary* of what's been seen? E.g., how do you mentally represent the fourteen cards in the example that begins 244? (I'm not merely curious here; your answer may help people answer the question you are asking about computing probabilities.)

Comment: @BarryCipra I'm an amateur card counter myself. (Don't tell the casinos!) Card counters don't remember the order in which cards have left the deck, because that information is irrelevant. Most counters only keep track of a single number, the "running count". The sequence of cards given in the question contains equally many "high" cards (10 and greater) as "low" cards (6 and less), so in the Hi-Lo system, the running count for that sequence is 0.

Comment: @TannerSwett, I was a card counter myself a long time ago, so I agree with what yous said. But I'm asking the *OP* how *he* approaches things. He may have some sophisticated system in mind that keeps track of more detailed information than a running total of high vs. low (though I'd be surprised if his system considers the order of appearance to be of any importance -- I think we all assume the casinos shuffle their decks thoroughly enough that all shuffles are equally likely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple formula is that if you have a particular card $c$ in mind, then the probability that the next card dealt will be a $c$ card is

$$\frac{\text{number of $c$ cards remaining in the shoe}}{\text{total number of cards remaining in the shoe}}.$$

If there are any face-down cards on the table (or in the discard tray) that nobody has looked at, then those cards need to be treated as though they were still in the shoe.

If the dealer has peeked at his hole card in order to check for a blackjack, then things get a little more complicated. I don't have the formula off-hand.

Does this answer your question?